# Android - Disable right swipe from ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK screen

Tags: android, android-intent, kiosk-mode

We have a commercial application that runs on an Android tablet.  It is the activity that is launched on startup, and we have taken steps to prevent the user from access the android system.  This includes removing the home and back buttons, as well as settings such as:

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Settings.Global.putString(cr, "policy_control", "immersive.full=*");
    Settings.Secure.putInt(cr, "user_setup_complete", 0);
```

We have a new requirement to allow the user to connect to WiFi.  For this, we would like to access the system wifi settings programatically, via an intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
    intent.putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true);
    intent.putExtra("extra_prefs_set_next_text", (String)null);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This works great - allowing the user to do whatever is needed to establish the wifi connection, including a back button to get back to our app.  However, I have found that if you swipe right from the left edge, the Settings navigation drawer opens, and now the user is able to access the android system.

Is there a way to prevent this drawer from opening?  Maybe prevent swipe actions while this screen is up, but then to allow them when our application is on top?

Answer (score 0):

We discovered a partial solution.  If you include this extra with the intent:

```
    intent.putExtra(":settings:hide_drawer", true);
```

It will successfully prevent the drawer from opening on this page.  However, if you select any of the menu items (such as "Configure Wi-Fi" or "Advanced"), this causes a new intent to be sent, and the drawer is accessible again on these pages.  Go back to the original WiFiSettings page from the sub setting pages, and the drawer is disabled again.

Looks like we may have to modify the Android source in order to get the behavior we are looking for.